# Python pep8 - method name with country name?

Tags: python, pep8

How can I define a method? How will be right?

```
def translate_to_english
    pass

def translate_to_English
    pass
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables did you read this ?

Comment: The general guideline is to use all lowercase in method names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Python [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
>   prevailing style Variables...

Use the function naming rules:

> lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve
>   readability.

I prefer is `translateToEnglish` instead `translate_to_english`